# ¿traer dato de una BD SQliteAdmin a un textField en java?

Tags: java

tengo un inconveniente el cual es que no se hacer para traer un dato de una bd a un textfield en java, realice a conexión a la bd e inerte un dato, pero como comente no se como traerlo a un textfied al iniciar el programa, este es mi código
Código de conexión a la BD

```
public class conexion {
String strConexionDB ="jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Mercadeo Eforsalud/Documents/Desktop/bd/inscripciones.s3db";
Connection conn = null;
public conexion(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strConexionDB);
        System.out.println("conexion establecida");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("conexion fallida"+e);

    }
};
```

AQUI ES PARA LA EJECUCION D ELA SENTENCIA

```
    public int  ejecutarSentenciaSQL(String strSentenciaSQL){
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(strSentenciaSQL);
        pstm.execute();
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

//Y ASI GUARDO EL DATO EN LA BD
//Envio un contador a un textfiel

```
    txtFormVTotal.setText(String.valueOf(MatriculadosTotal));
    
    String trSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO contador (ID,formVendiTotal)"+" 
    VALUES (null, '%s')",oPersonas.getMatriTotal());
    objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(trSentenciaInsert);
```

el El select, y como le saco el dato

```
conexion objConexion = new conexion();
ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM 
contador");
```

me disculpan si no comprendo bien, esque soy nuevi en esto

esta es la bd
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar una sentencia del tipo `SELECT`, leer el `ResultSet` y mostrar los datos en el textfield. Intenta un código y si tienes problemas o errores te ayudaremos a corregirlos. Por el momento, faltan detalles en tu pregunta, pulsa en [edit] para completarla con el código que estás intentando para lograr lo que planteas en la pregunta.

Comment: *"un dato ... un textfield ..."* ¿Cuál dato y a cuál TextField?

Comment: un string, quiero traerlo a una caja de texto,

Comment: No estás leyendo tu `ResultSet`, intenta algo así: `while (resultado.next()) {int counterID = rs.getInt("ID");System.out.println(counterID);}` Debes aplicar un *get*+Tipo de dato, según el tipo de dato de la columna sea entero, cadena, etc. Revisa la documentación de `ResultSet`. Aquí, a modo de ejemplo, simplemente se muestra el valor de la columna `ID`, lo puedes modificar, para poner el dato en un textfield o donde quieras.

Comment: gracias, ya lo realizar como me dijiste y me funciono, enserio te agradezco no había podido desde hace días